# Embedded RavenDB in NServiceBus.Host based endpoint

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I'm implementing an endpoint using NServiceBus.Host, and I want to use RavenDB embedded for Timeouts persistence. In the "RavenDB persistence Sample" on docs.particular.net there is a RavenHost that sets up RavenDB document store. However, this needs to be disposed. But it doesn't seem there's any appropriate place to hook this up in NServiceBus.Host, which appears to have only the IConfigureThisEndpoint.Customize extension point.

I'm facing the same problem in regards to the IoC container I use, which I pass to the BusConfiguration and then just hope it somehow handles dispose (I think I read somewhere that it actually handles this for containers). So perhaps there's some general info about NServiceBus.Host hook-in points I'm missing.

So my question is specifically how to handle an embedded RavenDB in NServiceBus.Host in terms of ensuring document store disposal?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to run RavenDB embedded instead of as it's own service? 

It makes more sense to share your persistence across endpoints...

Comment: Well, I was thinking that NServiceBus is all about distributed setup, like autonomous services that can be e.g. scaled independently and so forth. So sharing persistence seems to counter that principle. And then to simplify the setup (and deployment) I thought it was better to have an embedded RavenDB. But my thinking may be wrong(?)

Comment: Your approach is correct, you can deploy RavenDB on localhost:8080 for each machine, that will make it easy to deploy all endpoints that need to share their persistence on that machine... deploying it in process will not allow you to scale multiple message types to multiple queues for example... Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, but I still feel there can be situations, where one would like to have it embedded, for example if there is only one endpoint on a server. So it would still be interesting to get an answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you can get some idea as to how you can implement this yourself by looking at the code here: https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/blob/master/src/ServiceControl/Infrastructure/RavenDB/RavenBootstrapper.cs

Does this help?

Comment: It's definitely interesting to see how an embedded RavenDB is setup in ServiceControl. But it doesn't really seem to handle disposal of the documentStore, unless it happens behind the scene somehow by NServiceBus. However, I think I will go for another solution - maybe just use NHibernate persistence with SQL Server.